# Error in background image from asset in SliverAppBar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, appbar

I am making an app in which i am using a sliver app bar. I want to change the background with image from my asset but i am getting an error that " The Constructor being called isn't a const constructor"
I am new in flutter and unable to resolve this error . Please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkL08.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDSMc.png)

Comment: Just remove the `const` keyword

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are assigning a **constant FlexibleSpaceBar()** widget to **flexibleSpace** parameter which isn't supposed to be constant as **SliverAppBar** is a dynamic widget and it changes its size at run-time as the user scrolls it up and down so making **FlexibleSpaceBar()** widget const doesn't make any sense.

SO the solution is to just remove the **const** keyword before the FlexibleSpaceBar() constructor.